# Unexpected value 'AngularFirestore' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, firebase, code-injection, angular-module

hellow after i changed and installed couple if modules i got this messange and i don't know
i tried to add the missing modules and check my code but it's still the same error
tried to delete module of angularfirestore and still the same error with firestor i tried to check my modules carrfully one by one but still couldn't find the problem's origin i would like help in this thanks

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AngularFirestore' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
    at compiler.js:18645
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:18620)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:26029)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26010)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:25970)
    at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:143)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (core.js:17619)
    at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:17802)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:2430
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:18645
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:18620
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules @ compiler.js:26029
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:26010
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:25970
push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143
compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ @ core.js:17619
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:17802
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
content.js:48 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.engines is not iterable
    at E.updateSocialMedia (content.js:48)
    at new E (content.js:48)
    at Function.start (content.js:48)
    at Function.main (content.js:48)
```

my modules

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from "angularfire2/database";

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { rootRouterConfig } from './app.routes';
import { ExcelService } from '../app/services/excel';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AvatarDialogComponent } from './avatar-dialog/avatar-dialog.component';
import { EditUserComponent } from './edit-user/edit-user.component';
import { EditUserResolver } from './edit-user/edit-user.resolver';
import { NewUserComponent } from './new-user/new-user.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { FirebaseService } from './services/firebase.service';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule, MatInputModule, MatSliderModule, MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
import { StaffComponent } from './staff/staff.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AvatarDialogComponent,
    EditUserComponent,
    NewUserComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    StaffComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [AvatarDialogComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: false }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    AngularFirestore,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  providers: [FirebaseService, EditUserResolver,ExcelService,FormsModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `AngularFirestore` is not a module. This is already declared in the `AngularFirestoreModule` which you have already imported. In your imports array

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: false }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    AngularFirestore,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
```

**Remove** `AngularFirestore,` and remain with

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: false }),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
```